# Библиотека vk_api не возвращает URL выгруженного видео

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Делаю выгрузку видео из локальной папки на сервер ВК по примеру с гитхаба библиотеки. Видео выгружается в паблик, но не возвращается URL. Помогите понять причину и подскажите как это исправить?

```
import os
import vk_api
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


def main():
    token = os.getenv('vk_token')
    session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

    upload = vk_api.VkUpload(session)

    video = upload.video(
        'downloads/IMG_7460.MOV',
         group_id=221171917
    )

    vk_video_url = 'https://vk.com/video{}_{}'.format(
        video[0]['owner_id'], video[0]['id']
    )

    print(video, '\nLink: ', vk_video_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python\Telegram_and_VK_uploader_bot_2\temp2.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\Python\Telegram_and_VK_uploader_bot_2\temp2.py", line 28, in main
    video[0]['owner_id'], video[0]['id']
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам. Немного поменялся вид возвращаемого словаря и ключи в нем. Нулевой индекс теперь писать не нужно, и вместо `['id']` нужно писать `['video_id']`. Пример в документации обновить забыли. Всем спасибо за внимание!